# How to accept a line containing '999-' but dont contain '999-99.999'

Tags: c#, regex

can anyone help me in regex in question?

I need to create a pattern that locate a text '999 -' but does not contain any text with format '999-99.999'.

Example:

- "sequence: 999-9 project free"   ----> must locate
- "sequence: Code ag 1234-56.789"   ----> should not find

At the moment I have the following regex but does not work so you do not have .999 '999-99 '

```
^((?![0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}).)*$
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include several examples of what it should (and should not) match.

Comment: Agree w/ @Ken, we need to see more examples of what should and should not match.  I can't understand what you're trying to match from your question.

Comment: You only need to do a pattern to _locate_ the text `^\d{3}[ ]-$`

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you to try http://www.regexr.com/ anytime you need to write a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you're using a `.` and not a `\.` It should still work but I thought it was worth mentioning. I can't write comments yet so I made it part of my answer. Also, there is a space after `999` in your original question and I'm not sure if that is pertinent or not considering the regex you supply.

I tried this:

```
\b(999-)(?!99\.999)
```

If you're looking for any number you can replace those `9`s with `\d`s

I tried this at [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) and it works, but I second Ken who commented on your original post, I think you need more details.

Comment: Try 999- on the end of the line.

Comment: I see what you mean. So maybe a couple word boundaries are in order.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm probably better off deleting this until he clarifies his question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 #  @"(?s)^(?=(?:(?!\d+-\d{2}\.\d{3}).)+$).*\d+-.*$"

 (?s)              # Dot-All
 ^                 # BOS
 (?=               # Not this form anywhere in the string
      (?:
           (?! \d+ - \d{2} \. \d{3} )
           . 
      )+
      $ 
 )
 .* \d+ - .*       # Form needed
 $                 # EOS
```

Comment: I posted this simplified question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207365/how-to-accept-a-word-345-0-and-to-reject-555-55-00-in-the-same-line