# How to accept a word '345-0' and to reject '555-55.00' in the same line

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following questions:

I have the four texts:

1) "345-0 belongs to a contract"

2) "345-0 belongs to the contract 555-55.00"

3) "The account not found"

4) "345-0 belongs to a contract since 22/10/2014"

Results: 
1) Should find text

2) Should ignore text

3) Should ignore text

4) Should find text

How to mount a pattern that finds 345-0 (999-9) and there is no format 555-55.00 (999-99.99) in the same paragraph?

Comment: If you are looking for a specific range, ie: 345-0 through 999-9, you should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a regex.

Possible pattern can be `@"^[0-9-]+[^0-9-]*$"`

The above will find any string that starts with any combination of numbers and dashes followed by non-numeric characters.

```
Regex.IsMatch("345-0 belongs to a contract", @"^[0-9-]+[^0-9-]*$"); // True
Regex.IsMatch("345-0 belongs to the contract 555-55.00", @"^[0-9-]+[^0-9-]*$"); // False
Regex.IsMatch("The account not found", @"^[0-9-]+[^0-9-]*$"); // False
```

Comment: the pattern suggested does not work: 
I need mascara 999-99.99 should not exist in the paragraph, but any other characters, including numbers, letters, dashes, etc. for example: "345-0 belongs to a contract since 22/10/2014" fail...Should finde this text.

Comment: May be you should update your question then, to include more specifics of what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (almost same as last question)

```
 #  @"(?s)^(?=(?:(?!\d+-\d{2}\.\d{3}).)+$).*\d+-\d.*$"

 (?s)              # Dot-All
 ^                 # BOS
 (?=               # Not this form anywhere in the string
      (?:
           (?! \d+ - \d{2} \. \d{3} )
           . 
      )+
      $ 
 )
 .* \d+ - \d .*    # Form needed
 $                 # EOS
```